# How to correctly implement Deezer JS SDK to Angular application?

Tags: javascript, angular, sdk, deezer

I am trying to figure out how to implement Deezer JS SDK to angular app and need some help, could you explain how to do it?
Guiding the https://developers.deezer.com/sdk/javascript/init